# How to join Multiple

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is the code example
for three tables and I made a link on them
Now I want to add the age column from table D

```
    SELECT A.COD,a.namee, B.NAMEE,C.NAMEE
 FROM ((A INNER JOIN B ON A.COD = B.COD)
 LEFT JOIN C ON A.COD = C.COD)
```

I mean, this code is expected

```
SELECT A.COD, a.name , B.NAME,C.NAME ,D.Age
FROM ((A INNER JOIN B ON A.COD = B.COD)
LEFT JOIN C ON A.COD = C.COD) , D
```

But in access, an error message appears, the text of the message says that the JOIN method is not supported
Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Nobody can help you join tables together if they do not know what your tables look like. Maybe provide a sample dataset? or a simplified example for people to work with.
I will say that using a comma is the same as calling a 'CROSS JOIN'. I'm not sure if access cares that you are using that kind of join or not

Comment: There is a table of general accounts
and currency table
The opening balance table
cost center table

I want a query that shows the account number, account name and account currency type from the general accounts table and the currency table. By default, this is the first part of the query
Part Two: I want to inquire about the credit column and the debit column from the opening balances table
And I want to give an option to the user in the query if he wants to choose a cost center
Provided that the public account numbers do not disappear, they remain displayed to the user

Comment: This is roughly what I was able to find on the access database
 SELECT_Accounting_Directory.Account_No.Accounting_Directory.Account_Name, Currencies.Currency_Symbol, Opening_Balances.Local_Debit, Opening_Balances.Local_Credit, Opening_Balances.Foreign_Debit,Accounting_No.Accounting_Number.Accounting_No.Cross_Index. JOIN Opening Balances ON AccountingManual.AccountNo = OpeningBalances.AccountNo) LEFT JOIN CostCenter ON OpeningBalancesCenter=CostCenter.CenterNo. WHERE (Accounting Manual.Accounting_Manual.AccountNo.)=.(5) '101001. )=True)) ORDER BY Accounting_Directory.DESC_Account No.

Comment: It is expected that there is no data in the opening balances table, but I want all the records from the first part of the query, which is the account name, account number and account currency
It is a software method known as filling gaps from sparse data

Answer (score 0):

Access does not allow to do a direct cross-join (operator ",") involving an SQL expression that includes a different type of join. The solution is as simple as enclosing the first operation between parentheses and add another SELECT, as follows:

```
SELECT T_A.COD, T_A.Name_ , T_B.Name_, T_C.Name_, T_D.Age
FROM
(
SELECT T_A.COD, T_A.Name_ , T_B.Name_, T_C.Name_
FROM 
  (   T_A 
     INNER JOIN 
       T_B 
     ON T_A.COD = T_B.COD)
LEFT JOIN 
     T_C 
ON T_A.COD = T_C.COD 
)
, T_D
```

My advice is that you always enclose in a SELECT every individual join operation (with the exception of cross-joins) as good programming practice. There is no problem in doing a series of cross-joins because the cross-join operator is associative.